# Get Device Token List for APNS Service

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there any APNS endpoint by which I can get a list of all the device tokens on which my app is installed?
 I know there is a feedback service which gives a status of devices to whom messages are being sent. But I guess that is after the messages are sent.
 I need the device tokens in order to send messages to the apns server from this node.js module - [argon's node-apn](https://github.com/argon/node-apn)

Comment: i think you should upload the device information to your own server in 
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no  API that gives you a list of device tokens where your app is installed.

It's your responsibility to maintain such a list in your server. You add tokens to it every time your app registers for APNS on a new device.  You remove from it tokens returned by the feedback service.